# Rails Ajax single line RJS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

Everything I am reading about rails 3 and AJAX says that we should have

```
respond_to do |format| 
   @wines = Wine.all(:conditions => {:category => "Sparkling"})
   format.js
end
```

and then a seperate js.erb file that is

```
$("wines").update("<%=  escape_javascript(render :partial => "sparkling")%>")
```

but that one line js file seems a little extreme, can I do something like this:

```
respond_to do |format| 
   @wines = Wine.all(:conditions => {:category => "Sparkling"})
   format.js {render :js => '$("wines").update("<%=  escape_javascript(render :partial => "sparkling")%>"')}
end
```

and then leave out the extra .js.erb file
The problem I see here is a double render (am noob so I'm not sure)?  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline RJS is a bad practice, but you can use it like this:

```
def your_action 
  @wines = Wine.all(:conditions => {:category => "Sparkling"})
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.js {render :update do |page|
      page << '$("wines").update("<%=  escape_javascript(render :partial => "sparkling")%>"')
    end}
  end
end
```

**UPD**

No, it's not silly to store one more file. It makes your controllers cleaner. Look with `your_action.js.erb`

```
# your controller
def your_action 
  @wines = Wine.all(:conditions => {:category => "Sparkling"})
end
# your you_action.js.erb
$("wines").update("<%=  escape_javascript(render :partial => "sparkling")%>"
```

That is two lines instead of 6 :)

Comment: I understand the usefulness of it for larger bits of code, but am I out of whack feeling that an entire file to house a single line is silly?

Comment: No :) actually it is more than one line. I will update my answer a little